# Nginx location directive to transform locale in the url into a query string

Tags: nginx

I would like to rewrite all urls like:

```
http://example.com/en/foo
http://example.com/en
```

to:

```
http://example.com/foo?locale=en
http://example.com?locale=en
```

I've tried things like this (without success):

```
location ~ ^/([a-z]2)?/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^([a-z]2)/(.*) /$2?locale=$1;
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/([a-z]{2})(/.*){0,1} {
   rewrite ^/[a-z]{2}$ /?locale=$1 break;
   rewrite ^/[a-z]{2}/(.*)$ /$2?locale=$1 break;

location / {
    # I don't know what happend to your request after rewrite above
    # so I assume that you proxy pass it
    proxy_pass http://my.php.server/$uri?$query_string =404;
}
```

Here both your example match first `location` pattern. Inside this block the requested url is matched against to different patterns. 
If first pattern match then your second example is taken. 
If second pattern match then your first example is taken. 

Second `location` block works as *try it at the end* and here your rewrited url comes and are just used as they are. We are uring `$uri` here because `$request_uri` value is immutable. Value of param `$uri` after first location block will change to `/?locale=en` or `/foo?locale=en`. It doesn't contains query string so we have to mannualy assing it by using variable `$query_string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})$" "/?_LOCALE_=$1" break;
    rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$" "/$2?_LOCALE_=$1" break;
}
```